# How can I use a swap partition instead of a swap file

Tags: swap

I have a swap file in my file system `/swapfile` with 2GB, but I want to use a partition.

I created a partition using Gparted.
I removed my swap file using: `sudo swapoff /swapfile`
But I have a line on `/etc/fstab` with my old swapfile.
** **I Need To Inform My Ubuntu That I'm Using A Swap Partition.** **

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @vanadium, My question is the opposite of your suggestion. And I can't achieve my objective reading that another topic.

Comment: You are right: removed my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400322

First find the UUID of the swap partition:
`sudo blkid | grep 'TYPE="swap"'`

Then modify your `/etc/fstab` and replace `/swapfile` with **UUID=xxx**, using the **UUID** you got from the command above. The line that now has `/swapfile` must then look something like

`UUID=01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef   none       swap    sw        0       0`

The swap partition will be used after a reboot or running
`sudo swapon -a`